# How to download the last version of orion pep proxy?

Tags: fiware

I am installing the orion pep proxy but I think that I have not downloaded the correct version and I am having errors when using a local instance of KeyRock to validate and generate tokens.

I know that the latest version is 0.6.0 but i do not know how to complete the following command to obtain the last version:

./create-rpm.sh

Which is the difference between version and number?

Could you help me with this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea of having those two numbers is to help the Release Engineer in debugging their releases, or changes they make to the packagin process itself. The "release number" indicates the version of the package, not the one of the software. E.g.: if you are packaging version 0.6.0, you usually will use release number 1; but, if you find out that you want to add some dependencies for the spec, or you want to update the package to change part of the packaging process, for example, and you try to replace the installed version with a new one, the system will claim the package is up-to-date; in that case, you increase the release number (as the software itself, that is, the Node.js files that constitute the PEP Proxy) hasn't change.

Hope this clarifies the behavior.